# 'View online' [Weblink] links in Transactional emails

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid

The 'view online' subsitiution tags don't seem to work in Transactional email templates (we are *not* using the Marketing emails)

We've tried both versions `[Weblink]` and `[%weblink%]` and neither of them get automatically replaced

There is no documentation for the weblink for Transactional emails, only Marketing emails and Legacy Newsletters. I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem.

Do we have to generate our own 'view online' links now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently this is impossible. Transaction emails don't have the [Weblink] substitution tags, only Marketing emails do.

This is really unfortunate as we will have to build a custom solution.